# Excel: Searching for matches in a VBA Dictionary with wildcards on the dictionary values

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Trying to build a excel tool (spreadsheet/VBA) to go through and analyse data from imported text files and export them into a "clean" xlsx sheet without any of the code/smarts so these can be supplied to customers. Importing, sorting and general formatting is all sorted and works fine. Base spreadsheet/tool contains a separate sheet with 4 columns containing 4 sets of text codes. These codes are then put into separate dictionaries for each set and used to check each value in the relevant column of the imported data for any matches and apply additional formatting (color coding) to that cell.

```
Sub ColorMatchingRange(rng1 As Range, dict2 As Scripting.Dictionary, textColor As Long, fillColor As Long)
'Checks and colour codes matching data between dictionary and the range
    Dim unionRng As Range
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vals = Application.Transpose(rng1.Value)

    Set unionRng = rng1.Offset(, rng1.Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If dict2.Exists(vals(i)) Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng1(i, 1))
        Debug.Print dict2.Exists(vals(i))
    Next i

    Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, rng1)
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
        With unionRng
            .Font.Color = textColor
            .Interior.Color = fillColor
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine when the code in the dictionary exactly matches the code in the relevant column in the imported data. However, the issue comes when you need to start utilising wildcards on some of the codes. Read plenty of other discussions/documentation on how you can change the search term in the imported data (i.e. `vals(i)`) to include wildcards however this implies that the whole value you are searching for is contained within a value in the dictionary. Issue here is that the imported data i'm trying to search with will have an unknown about of additional text/code after the common section which can be found in the dictionary.

e.g. dictionary contains *"item"*, *"color"*, *"brand"*; imported search data contains *"item 2346"*, *"color asdf"*, *"brand(1234)"*

**What I want to be able to do** is ignore the additional data and have it as if the values in the dictionary itself can have a wildcard at the end of the "common code" and therefore will correctly format anything that starts with *"item"*, *"colour"* or *"brand"*.

*note the above code has more or less been copied from another problem/solution I found when building this and all the unnecessary bits removed/changed to suit this application. would link where but i've lost the link somewhere in the mass of stackoverflow and other websites I've looked at trying to solve this problem*

Comment: A dictionary provides no real benefit if you're not matching on exact keys - you could use an array of terms and just loop using `Like` instead.  Unless you have a lot of data it shouldn't be too much slower (and it will work, which is the main point here...)

Comment: Ended up reorganising it like you suggested @TimWilliams with two variant arrays of strings. It's slightly slower but not too bad. Could probably optimise it further but not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the code to use variant arrays as per @TimWilliams suggestion. Slightly slower to run but not too bad and not worth bothering further for my applications. For minor efficiency improvements (especially if your 2nd range/list) is quite long make sure you include the `exit for` so it stops searching for any additional and starts on the next value on your first list.

```
Sub ColorMatchingRange(rng1 As Variant, rng2 As Variant, textColor As Long, fillColor As Long)
'Checks and colour codes matching data between two dictionaries and the range
Dim unionRng As Range
Dim vals1 As Variant, vals2 As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

vals1 = Application.Transpose(rng1.Value)
vals2 = Application.Transpose(rng2.Value)

Set unionRng = rng1.Offset(, rng1.Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
For i = LBound(vals1) To UBound(vals1)
Debug.Print "i " & vals1(i)
    For j = LBound(vals2) To UBound(vals2)
    Debug.Print "j " & vals2(j)
        If (vals1(i) Like vals2(j) & "*") Then
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng1(i, 1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, rng1)
If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
    With unionRng
        .Font.Color = textColor
        .Interior.Color = fillColor
    End With
End If
End Sub
```